Are there any codes generating clusters of molecules?
I wanted to generate clusters containing 5 or 6 molecules, are there any python packages which take in an input xyz file and provide me with such cluster systems?. Just wanted to check to avoid re-inventing the wheel if it already exists.

Did you take a look at PACKMOL?

You may also consider using Crest which does conformer sampling using metadynamics on top of a semi-empirical method. The keyword --nci will be needed. This is a super easy way to generate clusters of basically arbitrary size and configuration in my experience.
